# Generate multiple signed URLs from array of filenames?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a Node / Express backend listing files from a secure GCS bucket using `.getFiles()`. I then loop through the array of filenames and generate signed URLs for each, then use probe-image-size to get the dimensions and finally push the results into a fileList array.

This is extremely slow and I have to imagine I'm going about this wrong.

Generating the signed URLs one by one seems to be the slowest part.

```
let fileList = [];

listFiles().catch(console.error);

async function listFiles() {
  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
  for (const file of files) {
    let fileName = file.id;
    let fullPath = await generateV4ReadSignedUrl(fileName); // it takes around 500ms per filename
    let result = await probe(fullPath[0]).catch(console.error);
    fileList.push(result);
  }
  console.log('fileList=', fileList);
  return fileList;
}

async function generateV4ReadSignedUrl(fileName) {
  console.log('generate signed url');
  // temp read access
  const options = {
    version: 'v4',
    action: 'read',
    expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000,
  };

  // v4 signed read URL
  const [url] = await storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .file(fileName)
    .getSignedUrl(options);
  return [url];
}
```

Ultimately the goal is to grab this list immediate with a self-invoking function, then have it waiting for React to call it via something like:

```
app.get('/api/photos', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.json({ fileList });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err', err);
  }
});
```

Comment: With node, you can easily perform concurrent processing. Call in async all your `generateV4ReadSignedUrl` method, and await all at the end. With that concurrency you can greatly improve the processing time. Sadly, I'm not a NodeJS developer and I can't guide you on that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution (plus some additional code to get image meta using `probeImageSize` package.

```
// get remote file names
listFiles();

async function listFiles() {
  console.log('list files');
  const signedUrlArr = [];
  // concurrently get GCS files
  const [fileNameArr] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
  // loop through fileNameArr and concurrently generate signed URLs
  for (const file of fileNameArr) {
    signedUrlArr.push(generateV4ReadSignedUrl(file.id));
  }
  Promise.all(signedUrlArr)
    .then((signedUrlArr) => {
      // concurrently get image meta using signedURLs
      getImageMeta(signedUrlArr);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

// concurrently generate signed URLs for each filename
function generateV4ReadSignedUrl(fileName) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const options = {
      version: 'v4',
      action: 'read',
      expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000,
    };
    const [url] = await storage
      .bucket(bucketName)
      .file(fileName)
      .getSignedUrl(options);
    resolve([url][0]);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

// (project specific) concurrently get image meta using probeImageSize module
function getImageMeta(signedUrlArr) {
  const probeResults = [];
  for (const url of signedUrlArr) {
    probeResults.push(probeImageSize(url));
  }
  // (project specific) take probeImage meta and create json file for `react-photo-gallery` (this can probably be done a better way that writing a json file)
  Promise.all(probeResults)
    .then((signedMeta) => {
      const galleryArr = [];
      signedMeta.forEach((metaObj) => {
        galleryArr.push({
          src: metaObj.url,
          width: metaObj.width,
          height: metaObj.height,
        });
      });
      console.log('galleryArr', galleryArr);
      fs.writeFileSync(
        '../frontend/src/helpers/photos.json',
        JSON.stringify(galleryArr),
      );
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

// concurrently get image meta data
function probeImageSize(signedUrl) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const meta = await probe(signedUrl).catch(console.error);
    resolve(meta);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```